# Html.HiddenFor causing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I try to add `@Html.HiddenFor(@Model.ID)` to my code, I get the following error when access the page:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I tried reading MSDN, but [the documentation is awful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703631.aspx) (they don't provide a single code example in the documentation for this method.

Here is my View:

```
@model CustomerService.Entity.Order
@using CustomerService.Entity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrderDetails";
}
<h2>
    OrderDetails</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("HandleSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Order #</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.ID
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Description</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.Description
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Salesperson Name</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.SalespersonName
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>
        Line Items</h3>

    <input id="btnAddLineItem" type="submit" name="AddLineItem" value="AddLineItem" />

    @Html.HiddenFor(@Model.ID)

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Line Item ID</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>Description</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.LineItems.Count; ++i)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.LineItems[i].ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.LineItems[i].Description
                </td>
            </tr>
        }</table>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HiddenFor` takes an expression.

```
@Html.HiddenFor( model => model.ID )
```

Answer (score 4):

`HiddenFor` method should get an `Expression` as a parameter not a value:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

Instead of: `@Html.HiddenFor(@Model.ID)`

Method signature:

```
HiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>,
                             Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>)
```

In plain text you should give an `Expression` that gets an "instance" of the type of your model(in this case `CustomerService.Entity.Order`) and returns the desired property(in this case `ID`)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor.aspx)